# Will learning_rate be automatically adjusted using "adaptive" strategy for VowpalWabbit Python online learning?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I see that the documentation at [VowpalWabbit command-line](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-Line-Arguments) has mentioned about `--adaptive` learning rate strategy as the default. I am **not** using the command line utility to train, i.e: passing the whole training file through the command line. Instead, I have a large dataset which I am iterating over and training one sample at a time using the Python online learning method as following:

```
for example in train_examples:
    model.learn(example)
```

Question:

1. When using the Python online learning method, is the learning rate is also adjusted automatically using the `adaptive` strategy or it only works if the training file is passed through the command-line utility?
2. From my understanding, the `--passes` argument only works when the training file is passed through the command-line utility (correct me if I'm wrong). So, the `--decay_learning_rate` argument as follows also does not work in the Python online learning method?

> --decay_learning_rate arg (=1)
> Set Decay factor for learning_rate
> between passes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no single global learning rate.

There are:

- A single default *initial* learning rate (`-l <arg>`)
- Multiple (per-feature) learning rates maintained while learning

Learning rates aren't constant, they decay over time as the model converges.  They have good defaults, so you shouldn't normally worry about them while training.

In some more detail:

- Initial learning rate, optionally set with `-l [ --learning_rate ] arg`. It is set once at the beginning of learning, not at every example processing, and has a good default, so there's no need to specify it. If you do specify it it will affect how fast you learn (how large are the updates) at the start, but the effect will decay as the learning progresses and automatic adjustments are applied. Setting this initial learning-rate to a high value is not advised since it might lead to early over-fitting.
- `--adaptive`, `--normalized` and `--invariant` are 3 independent boolean switches that are turned **on** by default. Unless you really know what you're doing, just leave them alone (don't specify them) and they will be in all in effect. These 3 switches affect *updates* on the individual (per feature) and are orthogonal to the initial learning rate. If you explicitly ***turn-on*** one or more of these 3 switches, at the start of training (not with every example), it will implicitly ***turn-off*** the ones which you didn't explicitly specify.
- As you figured, `--decay_learning_rate arg` is only relevant when multiple passes are in effect, so you don't need to worry about it given you don't use multiple passes. It will affect an *additional* magnitude of adjustment between passes.

Plotting your average-loss, (or loss "since last" column) over time can help you figure out convergence. You may use [`vw-convergence`](https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-convergence) from the `vw` source `utl` directory, feeding it your progress output to see your convergence. `vw-convergence` is a CLI utility that requires perl and R.

Here's an example of a chart generated by `vw-convergence`

[image: vw online training loss convergence/progress]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a Python API for the `vw-convergence` or it's a command-line utility? I cannot find it in the VowpalWabbit documentation.

Comment: It is a very old CLI utility.  You can get it from the source tree here:  https://github.com/VowpalWabbit/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/utl/vw-convergence

Comment: @Jack, if the answer was helpful/useful, please accept and/or upvote it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't accept the answer earlier. Accepted it.